# How to live reload with Cordova ionic project with Xcode emulator

Tags: ionic-framework

When i run ionic project in vs code using **ionic cordova run ios -l --external** comand but can't reload live.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

that is the incorrect command, it is `cap` not `cordova`

```
ionic cap run ios -l --external
```

Comment: This is capasitor comand.. i want run using cordova.